# ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil, Python OSX 10

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

I installed Matplotlib with homebrew along with some other things the [link](https://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/) I followed said were necessary, with the exception that I already had python installed from before. Just after that if I ran python calling for pyplot it would tell me I needed to install X11, didn't know what that was so looked it up, found this [link](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/matplotlib-Installation-Guide-for-Mac-OS-X), installed the app and followed those steps.

Now when running the code I get the following error.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

I know python-dateutil is installed, so is matplotlib, numpy and the others in the links. Checked them all in the terminal, so don't understand what the problem is.

Also numpy on it's own works fine, it gives me no errors if that's the only package being used, matplotlib is the problem. Also made sure of upgrading the pip install, matplotlib, numpy and dateutil and nothing changed.

It's not a duplicate from the question. That question was resolved by installing dateutil, I already have it installed.

Comment: `I know python-dateutil is installed` - this is not how debugging works. Matplotlib clearly cannot find it, so the next step for you is to verify what version it is and where it is installed to.

Comment: How do I do that? I am new to all this. Have just followed steps from the internet and what I have gathered from existing questions only.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That person needed to install dateutil and that was the fix. I already have it installed.

Comment: Did you try `import dateutil` to see if it's present in `sys.path`?

Comment: I am sorry but I dont know what sys.path is. But if I try to "import dateutil" it says "ImportError: No module named dateutil"

Comment: I added below import a "sys.path.append()" with the directory I think dateutil is in but got the same error. I dont know what files dateutil is composed of but the directory i put was the one that has "python_dateutil-2.5.3.dist-info" in its files. That's the only file I can find that somehow says "dateutil" in its name. If I put "pip install python-dateutil" in my terminal it says it's already there, and if I add "--upgrade" it says it's up to date.